# Получить по 4 записи из каждой категории

Tags: sql, yii2, postgresql, activerecord, active-record

Написал такой запрос, но он возвращает 4 продукта, это понятно, т.к. limit 4

```
Category::find()
                            ->where(['category.id' => $ids])
                            ->joinWith([
                                'products' => function(ActiveQuery $query)
                                {
                                    $query->limit(4);
                                },
                            ])
                            ->groupBy(['category.id'])
                            ->having(['>=', 'COUNT(product.id)', 4])
                            ->asArray()
                            ->all();
```

Но как получить 4 продукта из каждлй категории, даже если в категории > 4 записей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select .... from category
join lateral (
select ... from products where products.category_id = category.id limit 4
) p on true
where category.id in (...)
```

Ваш activerecord весьма вероятно такое писать вовсе не умеет. Потому на выбор один быстрый запрос или использование activerecord.

---

Если данные о самой категории доставать не нужно - то запрос можно упростить до:

```
select .... from unnest(array[1,2,3]) as cat_id
join lateral (
select ... from products where products.category_id = cat_id limit 4
) p on true
```

Answer (score 0):

В posgresql присутствует функция rank, с помощью которой ты можешь отметить первые 4 записи каждой категории.

Если тебе нужно вернуть только информацию о продуктах (без деталей о категории) тогда можно обойтись таблицей products 
В примере ниже я предположил что в таблице products у тебя ключ тоже id

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT product_id, rank() over (PARTITION BY category_id order by id DESC) as ranking
    FROM products
    ) ranking_table
ON ranking_table.product_id and ranking_table.ranking <= 3
```

Теперь нужно просто перевести это в формат Yii

```
$subquery = Products::find()
    ->select([
        'id',
        'ranking' => new \yii\db\Expression('rank() over (PARTITION BY category_id order by id)')
    ]);

$limit = 4;
$res = Products::find()
    ->innerJoin(['ranking_table' => $subquery], [
        'AND', 'ranking_table.id = products.id', 'ranking<=:rankingnum'
    ], [':rankingnum' => $limit])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Если не обязательно привязываться к модели, можно использовать \yii\db\Query вместо ActiveRecord.

Если нужно добавить информацию о категории, тогда тут можно вставить еще один innerJoin на Category